# Failing to upload to Google Cloud Service with gsutil cp without any visible error, how to debug?

Tags: bash, gsutil

I'm running a custom made solution to manage podcasts recording. Everything is automated via bash scripts and at one point, I'm uploading a show to GCS, generating an XML for podcast's RSS then upload the RSS. This is what I am running in the bash script:

```
cd /path/to/tmp/files/
/path/to/gsutil cp -c -L /path/to/logs/gcloud_mp3.log *.mp3 gs://path/to/show/
wait
/path/to/gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://path/to/show/show.mp3
wait 

/path/to/php /path/to/rss_building_script.php

/path/to/gsutil cp -c *.xml gs://path/to/show/
wait
/path/to/gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://gs://path/to/show/rss.xml
wait
```

I *know* that my files are indeed located at /path/to/tmp/files/, I can see them. But sometimes, files won't get uploaded, and running the script won't throw any error. For example, last night, I recorded "show #1". It recorded, created mp3 file, uploaded the mp3 to GCS, created the XML, didn't upload the XML. I've seen some case where both files won't get uploaded.

Problem is, there is no error shown. In the case of show #1 last night, what I'm getting is

- copying mp3 file to GCS;
- setting ACL to the mp3 file;
- setting ACL to the xml file;
- error, XML file doesN't exist.

Where there should be an upload of an XML file, nothing happens. No error. Just nothing. How could I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

When programs fail silently like this, I generally turn to [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).  A command like this, for example:

`strace gsutil cp -c -L /path/to/logs/gcloud_mp3.log *.mp3 gs://path/to/show/ 2>&1 | tee /tmp/strace.gsutil`

Will generate tons of output.  Very near the end, when the program is collapsing under its error, there will likely be some system calls that give you hints as to what is wrong.  Look especially for [`E` errno constants](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), like `ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

For a further introduction, [this article has some good examples and patterns](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/).

Of course, this particular error could be a timing issue up-stream, meaning nothing at all on your side.  The strace output might provide some diagnostics (timeout?) or it might not.  In which case, I'd check for "weird" situations like UTF issues, file size limitations, parallel issues, connectivity, etc.

Comment: I'll give this a shot today, didn't know about strafe (this whole project of mine is a reason to learn bash) !

Comment: I finally went back to it. Posted the strace on paste bin, links are on @Mike Schwartz answer below.

Comment: Sadly, nothing jumps out at me as wrong in the strace.

Answer (score 1):

Does this problem happen every time you run your script? It's possible you're experiencing problems from eventual consistency of listing operations (which are implicitly performed when you run recursive operations or operations involving wildcards).

One thing you could do to avoid the problem is to set the ACL at the time you're performing the upload (which is possible since you're using a canned ACL rather than a custom ACL). For example:

/path/to/gsutil cp -a public-read -c -L /path/to/logs/gcloud_mp3.log *.mp3 gs://path/to/show/

With that you don't need to run the gsutil acl set commands, so listing eventual consistency will not matter.

Comment: I'll be looking into this next week when I'm back at the office! I'll followup when I'll have tested everything.

Comment: I'm so late answering to this, but the particular project I was working on was put aside for a while. Now that I'm back on it, I did change the command to set ACL at the time of upload. Without success. I'm still having an mp3 upload, and no XMLs. (Who was working just fine yesterday.) I'll try to run strafe like suggested above to check that out...

Comment: Here they are. (1) strafe of the MP3 file uploading (we can clearly see in the end that it does upload) : http://pastebin.com/ZrimVAbZ and (2) the XML file upload, where it lacks the uploading part: http://pastebin.com/Qeb7y3ZM. Is this of any help?

Comment: The strace output shows gsutil is only uploading the MP3 files. A couple thoughts: (1) Can you add "ls *.xml" to your script after running the php script, and post the output? (2) Can you change the gsutil cp command used to upload the XML files to include -L xml.log and post the log? If you'd rather not post these things publicly you can send to gs-team@google.com.